# Content under fullscreen dialog clickable

Tags: android, fullscreen, dialogfragment

In my app I am using fullscreen dialogs (DialogFragment). However content under these dialogs is still clickable when dialog is shown and it would be tiresome to disable/enable everything programmatically if dialog is currently shown or not.

I am using this code to show dialog:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();                
 transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 transaction.add(android.R.id.content,dialog).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Dialog then has background set in his layout file.

Any ideas how to stop this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Add this - `android:clickable="true"` - to the root element in your dialog xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common problem!

Set `android:clickable=true;` for the root layout of that dialog.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for.